# Android List View Scroll Checkbox state

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView with around 10 list items. In each list item I have a checkbox. At single time I would like to have only single check box checked.

If I select row 1 then all rest of 9 checkboxes should be unchecked and so on.

Please suggest me a solution.

Currently I'm struggling with this when the list is scrolled

Comment: Have You tried android:choiceMode  ?

Comment: Are you using a custom adapter for the `ListView`?

Comment: yes i have used custom adapter for listview and also tried choiceMode.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is you should track the last checked item, and in the `ListView`'s `onItemClickListener`, `setChecked(true);` the current item and `setChecked(false);` the last one; something like this:

```java
ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(/* id of listView */);
CheckBox lastChecked = null;
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new onItemClickListener(
    @Override
    onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View childView, int pos) {
        if(lastChecked != null) {
            lastCheckedBox.setChecked(false);
        }
        lastChecked = (CheckBox)((ViewGroup)childView).findViewById(/* id of checkBox */);
        lastChecked.setChecked(true);
    }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Map<String, Boolean> checkState;

public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
    this.checkState = new ArrayList<Boolean>(group_list.length);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_check_box, null);
    holder.checkbox = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    if(checkState.containsKey(String.valueOf(position))) {
                holder.checkbox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fill_check_button);
        holder.checkbox.setTag("0");
    }else{
                holder.checkbox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unfill_check_button);
        holder.checkbox.setTag("1");
    }

holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(holder.checkbox.getTag().toString().equals("0")) {
                    holder.checkbox.setTag("1");
                    holder.checkbox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fill_check_button);
                    checkState.put(String.valueOf(position), true);
} else {
                    holder.checkbox.setTag("0");
                    holder.checkbox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.un_fill_check_button);
                    checkState.put(String.valueOf(position), false);
                }
            }
        });
}
```